# Printing two separate SQL table data on the dynamically populated table - PHP

Tags: php

Can someone please help me on the following code? Simply put, I'm trying to get two separate SQL tables' data, one on the horizontal side (brands) and the other (distributors) on the vertical side of a dynamically populated table.

my issue is, if you go through the code I cant get the text boxes populated under each respective brand name I get to display from the database. The text boxes are appearing only for the first brand name column.

My second issue if how do I assign a unique ID or a name to a dynamically populated text box here?

```
    <?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

include ("../connection/index.php"); 
$sql="SELECT * FROM distributors WHERE rsm='".$q."'";
$sqlq="SELECT * FROM brands";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die ("SQL Error_er1");
$resultq = mysqli_query($db,$sqlq) or die ("SQL Error_er2");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Distributor</th>";
"<tr>";
while($rowq = mysqli_fetch_array($resultq))
    {
    echo "<td>" . $rowq['bname'] . "</td>";

    }
"</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='txt1'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating loop without relating to eachother, and the same goes for the execution of the querys...

If you want to solve it you will have to nestle the loops together, something like:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

include ("../connection/index.php"); 
$sql="SELECT * FROM distributors WHERE rsm='".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die ("SQL Error_er1");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Distributor</th>";
"<tr>";

//Go through all distributors
while($rowq = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>" . $rowq['bname'] . "</td>";

    //Show all brands for current distributor
    $sqlq="SELECT * FROM brands where distributor_id = " . $rowq['rsm'];
    $resultBrands = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die ("SQL Error Brands");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultBrands))
    {
           $id = $row['rsm'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['dname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='textBox[]'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    //End show all brands for current distributor

}
//End Go through all distributors
```

A better solution though, would be something like (of course $q has to validated before input inside of query and also binded with bind_param()).

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

include ("../connection/index.php"); 
$sql = " SELECT * FROM distributors d";
$sql .=" LEFT JOIN brands b ON (d.brand_id = b.brand_id)";
$sql .=" WHERE d.rsm=$q";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die ("SQL Error");

echo "<table border='1'>";

while($rowq = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = rowq['rsm'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowq['dname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowq['bname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='textBox[]'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Take notice of the name='textBox[]'. From PHP you can access the variable with $_POST['textBox'] (or $_GET['textBox'] and PHP will return an array).